# Operator overloading : member function vs. non-member function?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, member-functions, friend-function, non-member-functions

I read that an overloaded operator declared as member function is *asymmetric* because it can have only one parameter and the other parameter passed automatically is the `this` pointer. So no standard exists to compare them. On the other hand, overloaded operator declared as a `friend` is *symmetric* because we pass two arguments of the same type and hence, they can be compared.

My question is that when i can still compare a pointer's lvalue to a reference, why are friends preferred? (using an asymmetric version gives the same results as symmetric)
Why do STL algorithms use only symmetric versions?

Comment: Your question is really only about binary operators.  Not all overloaded operators are restricted to a single parameter. The () operator can take any number of parameters. Unary operators, on the other hand, can't have any parameters.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4421729/103167

Comment: This is one of many topics covered in the [C++ FAQ: Operator overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

Comment: By C++23, `operator[]` is also allowed to be overloaded as a member function with more than one parameter.

Answer (score 184, accepted):

If you define your operator overloaded function as member function, then the compiler translates expressions like `s1 + s2` into `s1.operator+(s2)`. **That means, the operator overloaded member function gets invoked on the first operand.** That is how member functions work!

But what if the first operand is not a class? **There's a major problem if we want to overload an operator where the first operand is not a class type, rather say `double`.** So you cannot write like this  `10.0 + s2`. However, you can write operator overloaded member function for expressions like `s1 + 10.0`.

To solve this *ordering* problem, we define operator overloaded function as `friend` IF it needs to access `private` members. **Make it `friend` ONLY when it needs to access private members.** Otherwise simply make it **non-friend non-member** function to *improve* encapsulation!

```
class Sample
{
 public:
    Sample operator + (const Sample& op2); //works with s1 + s2
    Sample operator + (double op2); //works with s1 + 10.0

   //Make it `friend` only when it needs to access private members. 
   //Otherwise simply make it **non-friend non-member** function.
    friend Sample operator + (double op1, const Sample& op2); //works with 10.0 + s2
}
```

Read these :
[A slight problem of ordering in operands](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jonmc/CSE2305/Topics/10.19.OpOverload/html/text.html#a_slight_problem_of_ordering)
[How Non-Member Functions Improve Encapsulation](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/184401197)

Comment: "Make it `friend` only when it needs to access private members..and when you dont have/are bored of writing accessors, right?

Comment: @Abhi : Choose your pick : Improved Encapsulation vs Lazy writing habit!

Comment: Are there known cases where you couldn't just avoid the `friend` keyword by having the global `operator+()` simply be `return op2.operator+(op1);`? In both cases, + would by default not modify the input Sample, and instead return a new rvalue instance of `Sample`, right?

Comment: @matthias, not all operators are commutative. Simple example is `a/b`.

Comment: Wouldn't `Sample&` in `friend Sample& operator + (double op1, const Sample& op2);` return a local reference that is no longer valid on return ? double return values (with double CTOR on Sample) on the friend or adding operator double() const member to Sample seem like good alternatives. You could also return by value on the friend operator.

Comment: A common way to avoid making your non-member operators require `friend` is to implement them in terms of the operation-assignment operators (which will almost certainly be public members).  For example, you could define `T T::operator+=(const T &rhs)` as a member and then define non-member `T operator(T lhs, const T &rhs)` as `return lhs += rhs;`.  The non-member function should be defined in the same namespace as the class.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy  `operator +=` normally changes `lhs`, but `operator +` normally not!

Comment: @ricky:  But if the lhs is a copy (as it is in my comment), then the fact that the lhs changes doesn't matter.

Comment: FWIW, nowadays, some people (myself included) recommend making the operator `friend` even if you don't need to access private members. Otherwise, observe the error message when you write `std::cout << something` without an `operator<<` overload; it lists every overload and why it didn't match. Hidden friends would instead hide the overload, improving the error message and protecting against less-than-perfectly constrained overloads. The lack of encapsulation is a shame, but hidden friends are the only mechanism in the language to hide overloads.

Answer (score 23):

It's not necessarily a distinction between `friend` operator overloads and member function operator overloads as it is between *global* operator overloads and member function operator overloads.

One reason to prefer a *global* operator overload is if you want to allow expressions where the class type appears on the *right* hand side of a binary operator.  For example:

```
Foo f = 100;
int x = 10;
cout << x + f;
```

This only works if there is a global operator overload for

> Foo operator + (int x, const Foo& f);

Note that the global operator overload doesn't necessarily need to be a `friend` function.  This is only necessary if it needs access to private members of `Foo`, but that is not always the case.

Regardless, if `Foo` only had a member function operator overload, like:

```
class Foo
{
  ...
  Foo operator + (int x);
  ...
};
```

...then we would only be able to have expressions where a `Foo` instance appears on the *left* of the plus operator.

Comment: +1 for making the distinction between member functions and non-member functions rather than member and friend functions.  I guess today we'd say "global or namespace scope."