# What is meant by non-member operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I was recently going over an article on operator overloading in which it mentioned **non-member operator overloading**.  I would appreciate it if someone could explain what is meant by non-member operator overloading with an example. I know what member operator overloading is (A method in a class which overloads an operator type (binary..etc) . I came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622330/operator-overloading-member-function-vs-non-member-function) on SO which makes me believe that the purpose of non-member operator overloading is to handle operator overloading in which the first parameter is a not a class and is simply a native type. Any links or examples that explain what non-member operator overloading is would definitely be appreciated.

Comment: The link you gave shows an example for non member operator overloading, used as you said to perform add on a primitive

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4421706/1410711) might be helpful...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means you can overload out-of-class:

```
struct X { int data; };

bool operator<(X const& a, X const& b) 
{
       return a.data < b.data;
}
```

This is useful for assymetrical overloading, where the left operand doesn't need to be your own type:

```
bool operator<(int a, X const& b) 
{
       return a < b.data;
}
```

A common idiom here is to combine it with *in-class* definition and friend declaration:

```
struct X 
{ 
    int data; 
    friend bool operator<(X const& a, X const& b) { return a.data<b.data; }
    friend bool operator<(int a, X const& b) { return a<b.data; }
};
```

Here, `operator<` is still technically **non**-member.

Another useful side-effect of this, as pointed out by DrewDormann below, is that the `(X const&, X const&)` will apply to any operands that are implicitly convertible to `X const&`, not just expressions of that exact type.

Comment: It's also useful for *symetrical* type conversion, allowing implicit type conversions for all involved operands.

Answer (score 0):

the most common way is to overload operator<< that will be called on `std::cout`:

```
namespace X { 
      class MyClass { 
       ...
       };  
}
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&, const X::MyClass&);
```

this is called on std::ostream member so you don't define it inside your class.
however sometimes the functionality cannot be achieved via the public interfaces (because your operator needs access to data representation).