# Declaring a operator+ function in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a class Samp. In Samp.cpp, I can define/declare a function like

```
 Samp& operator+(Samp& other) {
  std::cout << "something";
  return other;
}
```

What is this function exactly? How do I call it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622330/operator-overloading-member-function-vs-non-member-function

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is actually a unary `+`, you call it like this:

```
Samp s;
+s; // <-- here
```

Comment: @buc Wat? Of course C++ has unary `+`. Want some fun with unary `+`? Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889028) out :)

Comment: Well, it could be binary member `operator+` - but the fact that it returns reference kind of makes it wrong, but it's wrong anyway because of unclear semantics.

Comment: @DanielFrey: That's brilliant. It hadn't occurred to me that that would be a free function.

Comment: @Daniel Frey: Sorry, my mistake. You're right.

Comment: Unless this is defined within the class declaration, then it is the addition operator.

Comment: +1, unary makes much more sense than binary, since it is returning a reference.

Comment: @ZacHowland In that case it most probably won't go into the `.cpp` file.

Comment: @DanielFrey *probably*, but you and I both know poor code exists.