# Is there compareTo in C++

Tags: c++

This isn't a duplicate. I don't want to compare strings and the possible duplicate contains much to much information.

Is there a function `compareTo` in `C++` like in `Java`?

> int compareTo(T o)
>
> Parameters: o - the object to be compared.
>
> Returns: a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

-- [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CompareTo method in C++ similar to Java where you can use > < = operations on a data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20005392/is-there-a-compareto-method-in-c-similar-to-java-where-you-can-use-opera)

Comment: There will be a [default comparison operator (`operator<=>`)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison#Three-way_comparison) in the next version of c++.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I think you should add this comment as an answer to the linked question. And/Or add it as an answer here. (I find that the linked question contains too much details. And the question is about strings explicitly, whereas I want to compare (vectors of) ints)

Comment: Are you looking for [std::basic_string::compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare)?

Comment: @JesperJuhl I do **not** want to compare strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not until C++20's "spaceship operator" `<=>`, but you could easily define one:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
constexpr int compareTo(const T &a, const U &b)
{
    if (a < b) return -1;
    else if (a == b) return 0;
    else return 1;
}
```

This does of course assume types `T` and `U` have well-behaving comparison operators (no tricks).

Comment: Haha, space ship operator... Where does this interesting nickname come from?

Comment: @Constructor You know, I never thought to look it up, but [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-way_comparison#Trivia) says it was because it looked like a ship from a text-based Star Trek game.