# Operator overloading, const and #arguments errors

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Have this code in a simple class Time composed of two integers (day/hour) for an arduino project.

```
bool operator <= (const Time& other) const{
    return (day <= other.day && hour <= other.hour);
}
```

Although I do have an almost identical (and working) other class which uses the same syntax with the same non-static form... I'm getting the following errors :

```
error: non-member function ‘bool operator<=(const Time&)’ cannot have cv-qualifier
error: ‘bool operator<=(const Time&)’ must take exactly two arguments
```

I'm afraid that I'm at a loss despite having spent the last half-hour googling similar errors.
Thanks!

Comment: @juanchopanza _'Drop the last const'_ sure? The less/equal comparison operator shouldn't need to change anything in the underlying class to return right results.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It is a non-member.

Comment: @juanchopanza Not from the sig as shown ... (But from the error message of course ;D!)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No, from the errors :-)

Comment: _'Have this code in a simple class ...'_ You don't have this code declared or defined in a class!

Comment: Reading is hard? `error: non-member function`. Read that 3 times. Then you have my permission to /headdesk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this operator was declared as a class member function then you need to define it the following way

```
bool Time::operator <= (const Time& other) const{
    return (day <= other.day && hour <= other.hour);
}
```

Also take into account that the condition inside the operator is invalid. 
There should be

```
bool Time::operator <= (const Time& other) const{
    return ( day <= other.day ) && ( other.day > day || hour <= other.hour ) );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I overlooked forgetting Time::, that was it.

Comment: @user3299912 And is it you who have downvoted my answer?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow _'@user3299912 And is it you who have downvoted my answer?'_ Of course not, he/she even can't ... (I didn't neither)

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I think that it is you.:) Because every time when I have been downvoted you appear.

Comment: It wasn't not me (check my reputation profile)!! I just notice your 'delusional' chase for downvoters of your answers, and comment it. I think the kind of `mechanism` you're experiencing here (as I could observe so far), is the higher rep you get, the more you're exposed for downvotes. The reason I'm appearing often along you, might be we have the same daytime zones, and I'm often on here ...

Comment: @@πάντα ῥεῖ By the way if you a Greek then I would like to ask what does name Penelopa mean?

Comment: @juanchopanza Do you want to say that all will be ahead?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I'm german, I have given some reasoning for the nick in my profile, you're welcome to have a look.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow No, I just forgot how many rep points you need to see down and up votes. I thought maybe you couldn't see it, but you can :)

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I was in Eastern German. For example in Leipzig, Meisen, Dresden.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow At least it was me that gave you the least 10+ to the 10K. I rarely downvoted answers of yours, if ever ;) ...

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ  There is a wrong meaning of name Penelope. It seems that it is only me who knows its true meaning.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow There's some other hint I found (not in english), that _Penelope_ could mean: _'She's going to rip your skin off'_ ;) ...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48315/discussion-between---and-vlad-from-moscow)

Answer (score 3):

You have a non-member comparison operator. It makes sense for it to be a non-member rather than a member, but it requires two arguments, and cannot be `const`:

```
bool operator <= (const Time& lhs, const Time& rhs) { .... }
```

Also, you need to fix the logic of the comparison. I am very lazy so I would do it like this:

```
#include <tuple>

bool operator <= (const Time& lhs, const Time& rhs)
{
  return std::tie(lhs.day, lhs.hour) <= std::tie(rhs.day, rhs.hour);
}
```

See more on [*operator overloading* here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading).

Comment: For the OP: I think you want `lhs.day < rhs.day || (lhs.day == rhs.day && lhs.hour <= rhs.hour)`

Answer (score 1):

```
error: non-member function ‘bool operator<=(const Time&)’ cannot have cv-qualifier
```

You cannot add const qualifiers to a non member function. 
Let me explain you why

The const after a member function guarantees that this function will not change any member variable of `this` . Now what would a static function guarantee if you don't have any `this` to refer to?

```
error: ‘bool operator<=(const Time&)’ must take exactly two arguments
```

There are 2 ways of overloading operators. You can make them member functions (without the static), but if you want to compare `int` and `Time` for example.. Lets write it out:

in your Time class, write out the following operator:

```
bool operator<=(int rhs) const {return this.minutes <= rhs;}
```

now, let us compare our data:

```
Time time;
int integer;
if(time <= integer) {} //This will compile
if(integer <= time) () //This will not compile
```

lets see why that is:

```
if(time <= integer) {} //Will expand to this:
if(time.operator<=(integer)) {}
```

now can you guess what this does?

```
if(integer <= time) {} //Will expand to this:
if(integer.operator<=(time)) {}
```

There is no such operator for a default type like integers, and you can't simply just add one to the integer type.

The solution to this are the static operators.
To cover both cases (int <= Time and Time <= int)
you can write this operator as well in your Time class

```
static bool operator<=(int lhs, const Time& rhs) {};
```

The parameters are the left side of the comparison and the right side of the comparison.

I also suggest you to take a look at juanchopanza's link:

> See more on [operator overloading here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading).

and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622330/operator-overloading-member-function-vs-non-member-function) for the difference between member function operators and non member function operators.