# User-defined class in std::map: Invalid operands to binary expression

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to use a class as the key in a std::map.

```
std::map<Type, value> collection;
```

Although I defined `operator<`, the key isn't accepted: `Invalid operands to binary expression ('const Type' and 'const Type')`.

```
class Type {
public:
    inline bool operator< (const Type& rhs) { /* ... */ }
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Your member functions needs to be `const`: `inline bool operator< (const Type& rhs) const;` Even better, implement it as a non-member `friend` function for symmetry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must define your `operator<` as

```
inline bool operator< (const Type& rhs) const { /* ... */ }
```

because map stores `const key` internally.

---

To expand a bit I'd also suggest (like [dyp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/420683/dyp) already did in the comments) That you use non-member operator overloads when possible. There are various advantages to them. I won't list them here since there already is good information on the advantages/differences, just let me link you to [Operator overloading : member function vs. non-member function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4622330/1942027).

Comment: What a dumb mistake to overlook. Thanks!