# Problems with the conversion operator and function lookup

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I have a class, let's call it `Wrapper`, that wraps a given type, let's say `MyClass`.
In reality, `Wrapper` is a class template, but I think that's not relevant here.

`Wrapper` exposes the wrapped `MyClass` by means of a conversion operator (just for reading).

When I create an operator for `MyClass` as free function (in my example a unary minus operator), this works as expected, I can use the operator also on the `Wrapper` class.

If I, however, implement the operator as a member function, the compiler complains: `error: no match for ‘operator-’`.

I thought the free function and the member function are equivalent in this case, why aren't they?

Is there a way to change the `Wrapper` class that a member operator or `MyClass` works?

If there isn't, does this suggest that it is in general preferable to implement an operator as free function instead of as member function?

Here's some code to illustrate the problem.

```
struct MyClass {
  // This doesn't work:
  void operator-() const {}
};

// It works with this instead of the member operator:
//void operator-(const MyClass&) {}

struct Wrapper {
  operator MyClass() const { return MyClass(); }
};

int main() {
  -Wrapper();
}
```

Here's a live example: http://ideone.com/nY6JzR

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622330/operator-overloading-member-function-vs-non-member-function

Comment: A conversion will be only executed, if you are requiring with a cast, or have a type that can be deduced as `MyClass` at the left side of an assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question** I thought the free function and the member function are equivalent in this case, why aren't they?

**Answer**

In order for `-Wrapper()` to work correctly, the compiler has to perform a lookup for `operator-`. It looks for the name `operator-` in the default namespace, in the class `Wrapper`, and the namespace where `Wrapper` is defined. It doesn't look at other classes and namespaces for the name.

That explains the compiler error when the `operator-()` is moved to `MyClass` and why it succeeds when it is defined as a non-member function.

**Question** Is there a way to change the `Wrapper` class that a member operator or `MyClass` works?

**Answer** There are two ways to resolve this.

1. Make the operator functions for `MyClass` non-member functions.
2. Create operator functions in `MyClass` as well as `Wrapper`, with the implementations in `Wrapper` being simple pass through functions. The good thing about this is that then you don't have to care whether the operator functions in `MyClass` are member functions or non-member functions.

**Question** If there isn't, does this suggest that it is in general preferable to implement an operator as free function instead of as member function?

**Answer** This can be a policy decision based on the choice you make to the previous answer.

Comment: It looks for the name `operator-`.

Comment: In my concrete use case, I prefer to keep the `Wrapper` as simple and general as possible (as it's in reality a class template), therefore I'll change `MyClass` as suggested in option 1.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought the free function and the member function are equivalent in
>   this case, why aren't they?

Lets see what happens when a conversion operator is used.

Essentially, there is a global operator function, which has a parameter of type `MyClass`. Now, since Wrapper has a conversion operator, the call `operator-( Wrapper() )` will be inspected by overload resolution to find the best match - and overload resolution finds that there is a global operator function with parameter `MyClass const&` (or similiar). Then it tries to convert the `Wrapper` prvalue to `MyClass const&` and sees that there is a user-defined conversion sequence: One that uses the conversion operator to convert the Wrapper-object to a `MyClass` object, which then can be used to (copy-)initialize the reference.

If the operator function is a member instead, there is a problem: A global function call of the form `operator-( Wrapper() )` does obviously not yield any viable functions. But the one that assumes the operator function is a member doesn't yield anything either - because `operator-` is not a member of `Wrapper`, therefore `Wrapper().operator-()` doesn't work and doesn't yield any viable functions either.

Remember: A class with a conversion operator does not inherit the members of the target type. If you wanted that, you should have inherited `MyClass`.

> For a unary operator `@` with an operand of a type whose cv-unqualified
>   version is `T1` [...] three sets of candidate functions, designated
>   *member candidates*, *non-member candidates* and *built-in candidates*, are
>   constructed as follows:
>
> - If T1 is a complete class type, the set of member candidates is the
>     result of the qualified lookup of `T1::operator@` (13.3.1.1.1);
>     otherwise, the set of member candidates is empty.
> - The set of non-member candidates is the result of the unqualified lookup of
>     `operator@` in the context of the expression according to the usual
>     rules for name lookup in unqualified function calls (3.4.2) except
>     that all member functions are ignored. [...]