# Member is inaccessible. Overloading + Operator

Tags: c++

This is what I am trying to do. I'm trying to add each member of f1 and f2 together. _m is the slope and _b is the y-intersept.

```
linear_function operator +
        (const linear_function& f1, const linear_function& f2)
    {
        linear_function f;

        f._m = f1._m + f2._m;
        f._b = f1._b + f2._b;

        return f;
    }
```

But it says that the members are inaccessible.
Here is the .h file.

```
#ifndef LINEAR_H
#define LINEAR_H
#include <iostream>  // Provides ostream

namespace main_savitch_2
{

    class linear_function
    {
    public:
        // CONSTRUCTOR
        linear_function(double _b = 0.0, double _m = 0.0);
        // MODIFICATION MEMBER FUNCTIONS
        void set(double _b, double _m);
        // CONSTANT MEMBER FUNCTIONS
        double eval(double x) const;
        double root() const;
        double slope() const;
        double y_intersept() const;
        // CONSTANT OPERATORS
        double operator ( ) (double x) const;
    private:
        double _m, _b;
    };

    // NON-MEMBER BINARY OPERATORS
    linear_function operator +
        (const linear_function& f1, const linear_function& f2);
    linear_function operator -
        (const linear_function& f1, const linear_function& f2);
    linear_function operator |
        (const linear_function& f1, const linear_function& f2);

    // NON-MEMBER OUTPUT FUNCTIONS
    std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const linear_function& p);

}
#endif
```

I googled member vs nonmember operator overloading and made mine match what was shown. Not sure why I'm getting this error.

Comment: If you stick with this approach then make sure that your function bodies are also inside `namespace main_savitch_2` ! Because `::operator+` is a different function to `main_savitch_2::operator+` .

Answer (score 3):

Since members `_m` and `_b` are private, only members of the class and their friend functions are allowed to access them. In order to give outside functions access to members, you need to add `friend` keyword to operators' declarations inside the class, like this:

```
friend linear_function operator |
    (const linear_function& f1, const linear_function& f2);
friend linear_function operator -
    (const linear_function& f1, const linear_function& f2);
friend linear_function operator |
    (const linear_function& f1, const linear_function& f2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `friend` is your friend. Try to declare operators as `friend` functions within your class in order to provide access to class `private` members.

```
class linear_function
{
    ....

    friend linear_function operator +
        (const linear_function& f1, const linear_function& f2);
    friend linear_function operator -
        (const linear_function& f1, const linear_function& f2);
    friend linear_function operator |
        (const linear_function& f1, const linear_function& f2);
}
```

Comment: It says "invalid specifier outside a class declaration" when I put friend there.

Comment: @Canefan23 Add the function declarations (with `friend`) _inside_ the class declaration.

Answer (score 0):

A better option than using `friend` (especially if you wanted these operators anyway) is to use member assignment operators:

```
class linear_function
{
    // ...

    linear_function & operator+= (linear_function const &f)
    {
        _m += f._m;
        _b += f._b;
        return *this;
    }
};

// non-member but does not need special access rules now
linear_function operator+ (linear_function f1, linear_function const &f2)
{
    return f1 += f2;
}
```

**Update:** Included sample implementation of member `operator+=`. Normally I'd declare this in-line and put the definition in the `.cpp` file, but have shown the definition in-line here to keep the example simple.

Comment: I was going to upvote this, then realized that you were altering `this`.  Overload `operator +=` for that, and make `operator +` const and return a temp.

Comment: @Wug I'm not sure what you are trying to say. `operator+=` should alter `*this` because it means to assign to the current object. Altering `this` is not possible.  I don't know what you mean by "make operator+ const". Non-member functions cannot be `const`. I don't know what you mean by "return a temp".

Comment: @Wug anyway, updated my post to show a sample implementation of `operator+=`, hopefully it is clearer now

Comment: @Wug OK, your answer has member `operator+`, mine has non-member. As far as I'm aware, member `operator+` is considered bad style. If a function does not use `*this` at all then it does not make sense for it to be a non-static member.

Comment: It does use `this`, implicitly (via `_b` and `_m`).  And I have never seen anything that would indicate a member `operator+` is bad practice.  One thing that is definitely bad practice though is modifying arguments in an `operator+`.  The rule I've always heard and followed is when overloading operators, make their behavior analogous to operators on primitive types.  Your example would be like adding 1 + 2 and changing the value of 1 to 3, and is exactly how `operator +=` behaves when applied to other types (including your own class-member example).

Comment: OK, my last comment was bogus. But [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622330/operator-overloading-member-function-vs-non-member-function) for discussion of why non-member `operator+` is preferred. I think you misread my example, IDK how you think that `1 + 2` would change the value of `1`.  `f1` is passed by value, changes to `f1` do not affect whatever argument was passed by the caller of `operator+`.

Comment: You're right, I didn't notice that `f1` wasn't passed by reference.  And that answer isn't really relevant unless you're dealing with operators that take different types of arguments, the example he provides shows a member `Sample::operator+(const Sample &other)`.

Comment: @Wug I'm suggesting an improvement

Answer (score 0):

Consider something like this:

```
class linear_function
{
public:
    ...

    linear_function operator+(const linear_function &other) const
    {
        return linear_function(_b + other._b, _m + other._m);
    }
};
```

If you're unable to modify the definition of this class, just keep the out-of-class definition you have and use the getters `linear_function::slope()` and `linear_function::y_intercept()`, which fetch the values of `_m` and `_b`:

```
linear_function operator+(const linear_function &l, const linear_function &r)
{
    return linear_function(l.y_intercept() + r.y_intercept(),
                           l.slope() + r.slope());
}
```