# No operator "<" matches these operands operand types are: double < my_class

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, equality

I have two files:

`my_header.h`:

```
class my_class {
public:
    my_class();

    my_class(long long number);

    my_class(int number);

    my_class(double number);

    bool operator<(const my_class& rhs) const;

    //////
}
```

`my_class.h`:

```
my_class::my_class()
{
    //implementation
}

my_class::my_class(long long number)
{
    //implementation
}

my_class::my_class(int number)
{
    //implementation
}

my_class::my_class(double number)
{
    //implementation
}

bool my_class::operator<(my_class const& rhs) const
{
    //implementation
}
```

I do not understand, where I do mistake. I overload operator `<`. Also, I have `constructor` from `double` type.

Of course, Also, I implement other 5 operators (`==, !=, >, <=, =>`) by [this scheme](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators). Other operators are in the same namespace, but they are not member function.

**Test case is**:

```
my_class a = 2;
bool check = 5.17 < long_int1;
```

Comment: Provide a free function `bool operator<( double lhs, my_class const& rhs)` or create a temporary `my_class` from the double.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Operator overloading : member function vs. non-member function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622330/operator-overloading-member-function-vs-non-member-function)

Comment: clcto, why I have to provide this function? In fact, I have double constructor, why c++ does not cast double -> my_class?

Comment: @Denis see the link in the linked question: http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jonmc/CSE2305/Topics/10.19.OpOverload/html/text.html#a_slight_problem_of_ordering It is just the way it is parsed, the standard probably defines this

Comment: @AlanStokes, I tried this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/4622467/1756750 It does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules of C++ forbid the use of implicit conversions to create an
object on which to call a member function.  For this reason, *when* an
object supports implicit conversions, it is usual to define an binary
operators as non-members (friend if necessary).  For the comparison
operators, I have a simple template base class which will provide them,
provided my class has a member function `compare`, and inherits from it.

```
template <typename T>
class ComparisonOperators
{
    friend bool operator==( T const& lhs, T const& rhs )
    {
        return lhs.compare( rhs ) == 0;
    }
    friend bool operator!=( T const& lhs, T const& rhs )
    {
        return lhs.compare( rhs ) != 0;
    }
    friend bool operator<( T const& lhs, T const& rhs )
    {
        return lhs.compare( rhs ) < 0;
    }
    //  and so on.
};
```

You write this once, and then all you have to do is provide one (member)
function, and derive from it:

```
class MyClass : public ComparisonOperators<MyClass>
{
public:
    int compare( MyClass const& other ) const
    {
        //  return <, == or > 0, according to whether this is
        //  <, == or > other.
    }
}
```

Comment: am I right, that in MyClass::compare function I have to compute `diff` between `(*this)` and `other`, and then I have to compare `diff` and `0`?

Comment: @Denis You have to do whatever is necessary to be able to return an `int` with a value less than 0 if `*this` should be ordered before `other`, equal to 0 is `*this` should be considered equal to `other`, and greater than 0 if `*this` should be considered greater than `other`.  What this means in practice will depend on the actual data types in your object, and how you want to define the relationships.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the compiler has no way of knowing that you want to implicitly convert `5.17` to an instance of `my_class`. Think what would happen if you had two different classes that could accept a `double` as the only constructor argument. There are two ways of solving this.

1. Provide a conversion operator. This will allow the compiler to read your instance of `my_class` as a `double`.
2. Switch the order of the arguments. `!(my_class > 5.17)` should work fine.

Comment: what I do, if my_class can not be cast to double, and I can not to switch the order of the args?

Comment: If you do a comparison then that comparison must compute a "value" for your class and compare that to 5.17. This "value" can be returned by the conversion operator. In what way can you not switch the args? Just code readability?

Comment: my object can be more, then MAX_DOUBLE. I don't switch args, because this code is tested by external system.

Comment: As a hack the conversion operator could return min("value", MAX_DOUBLE).

Comment: He has provided a conversion: `double` to his class.

Comment: He provided a conversion constructor not a conversion operator.