# Overloading "<" operator for a class that I want to store in <map>

Tags: c++, stl

As far as I know, map keeps the data inside sorted and uses the "<" operator for this purpose. What happens if I don't overload "<" operator for that class?

One more question. Should I write the overloading function inside the class or outside the class?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, `std::map` doesn't use `<`. See the link above (btw., default is `std::less`)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't ask for _The STL_. Read the tag wiki please, before using this tag.

Comment: Your second question already has [good answers here on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622330/operator-overloading-member-function-vs-non-member-function). I answered your first question here because the information in the other question mentioned earlier in the comments doesn't address everything worth addressing here.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Actually, the tag wiki supports this interpretation of STL. I agree with you, but the tag wiki does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As far as I know, map keeps the data inside sorted and uses the "<" operator for this purpose.

Sort of, but not directly. `std::map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator>` uses `Compare` for that purpose. `Compare` defaults to `std::less<Key>`, which in turn typically defaults to using the `<` operator. However, even in the standard library implementation, there are cases where `std::less<Key>` behaves differently from `<`.

> What happens if I don't overload "<" operator for that class?

That depends. You can specify a different class as the `Compare` template argument which avoids using `std::less`. You can add a specialisation of `std::less` which avoids using `<`. But if you don't do either, you'll typically get error messages about `<` not being defined.