# Can't find mistake in overloading operator<

Tags: c++, makefile, operator-overloading

I tried to overload `operator <` for sorting the rooms based on price.

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
class Room{
    protected:
        int roomNo;
        int category;
        Client client;
    public:
        Room();
        Room(int no, int cat, Client cl);
        void printData();
        int charge();
        Room operator < (Room &r1);
};

Room Room::operator < (Room &r1){
    if(this->charge() < r1.charge()){
        return r1;
    }
    else{
        return *this;
    }
}
```

But the compiler gives me the following error when I try to use `operator<`:

```
main.cpp:(.text+0x2d8): undefined reference to `Room::operator<(Room const&)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x2ff): undefined reference to `Room::operator<(Room const&)'
[Error] ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile.win    recipe for target 'Ask01.exe' failed
```

Why doesn't the code compile?

Comment: Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading?rq=1, your function signature is incorrect. Hint: the error tells you what it should be

Comment: Shouldn't that be `Room& Room::operator < (const Room& r1)`?

Comment: Whet I tried that i got this: " 39 7 [Error] prototype for 'Room& Room::operator<(Room&)' does not match any in class 'Room'"

Comment: That's because the declaration is also wrong.  Note parameter is `const`.

Comment: If I use const i cant use the function charge because it's  a non-static function

Comment: You mean it's not `const`.  It doesn't modify `Room` so it should be.

Comment: Please refrain from using the `this->` syntax.  C++ is not Java, C# or Smalltalk.  If you need to access a member variable, access it directly.  If your parameter names are the same as the member names, change them.

Answer (score 4):

Your class `Room` has a member functon with signature `Room operator<(Room& r1)`. However, this is not signature to be used as overloaded `operator<`. Change your definition to

```
Room operator<(const Room& r1);
```

And your declaration to

```
Room Room::operator<(const Room& r1)
{
    /* code */
}
```

Also, it is considered better practice to overload operators as friend non-member functions (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622330/operator-overloading-member-function-vs-non-member-function)).

Also, I would consider to change return value of `operator<` to `const Room&` to avoid certainly unnecessary copy.

Anyways, why do the return value of `operator<` is not `bool`? It might confuse someone.

```
Room first, second;
if (first < second)
    doSomething(first);
else
    doSomething(second);
```

might be little longer than simple `(first < second).doSomething()`, but your intuition is definitely clearer.

Also, if you insist on defining `operator<` as member function, I would recommend to declare it as `const` (like `bool /*Room*/ operator<(const Room& r1) const;`. You would have to declare as const also `int charge()` and maybe even `Client::getTheD`). Look at more about [const correctness](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness).

Comment: Shouldn't we recommend that the return type of `operator <` be `bool`?

Comment: @JohnZwinck good point :)

Comment: Actually that is what i did (the last one) but i had a mistake in a function in main() and the compiler didnt catch it so it resolved in a makefile error

Comment: Minor correction: `operator < ()` should be `const`.

Comment: Also I use Room instead of bool so i can make inline statements of the , eg (r1 < (r2 < r4))

Comment: @Sini By the way, with regards to your original plan (return the smaller of the two elements): Once you have defined proper comparison operators, you can use [`std::max()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) and [`std::min()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min) to get what you want.

Comment: @mindriot It should in general, but is is not a condition. In OP's case, he would have to declare `int charge()` as `const` as well and maybe even `Client::getTheD`.

Comment: @Zereges you're right that it is not a condition (hence I said _should_, not _must_). But [const correctness](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness) is strongly recommended (hence my comment).

Comment: @mindriot I agree with you, but the code would not compile as is (hence my comment).

Comment: @Zereges true, fair enough :)

Comment: Thank you all , the code did actually run , my mistake was an invalid call to a function that the compiler didnt catch . But yes I should have made it const :)