# Error while overloading operator +,-,*,/ in c++

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, overloading

I am getting error while trying to compile the following code. I am beginner. Please help me figuring it out. I am trying to overload the operators _,+,/,*. It shows error while compiling. Should I use "friend" to solve this?

```
#include<stdio.h>

class complex{
private:
    double real; //real part of complex
    double imag; // imaginary part of complex
public:
    complex(double r=0., double i=0.):real(r),imag(i)
    {
    } // constructor with initialization
    complex(const complex&c):real(c.real),imag(c.imag)
    {
    } // copy constructor with initialization
    ~complex()
    {
    } // destructor
    double re() const
    {
        return real;
    } // read real part
    double im() const
    {
        return imag;
    } // read imaginary part
    const complex& operator=(const complex&c)
    {
        real=c.real;
        imag=c.imag;
        return *this;
    } //assignment operator
    const complex& operator+=(const complex&c)
    {
        real += c.real;
        imag += c.imag;
        return *this;
    } // addition of current complex
    const complex& operator-=(const complex&c)
    {
        real -= c.real;
        imag -= c.imag;
        return *this;
    } // subtract from current complex
    const complex& operator*=(const complex&c)
    {
        double keepreal = real;
        real = real*c.real-imag*c.imag;
        imag = keepreal*c.imag+imag*c.real;
        return *this;
    } // multiply current complex with a complex
    const complex& operator/=(double d)
    {
        real /= d;
        imag /= d;
        return *this;
    } // divide current complex with real
    void print(const complex&c)
    {
        printf("(%f,%f)\n",c.re(),c.im() );
    } // printing complex number
    friend complex operator !(const complex& c)
    {
        return complex(c.re(),-c.im());
    }
    friend double abs2(const complex& c)
    {
        return c.re()*c.re()+c.im()*c.im();
    } // absolute value of complex
    const complex& operator/=(const complex&c)
    {
        return *this *= (!c)/=abs2(c);
    } // divide the current complex by a complex
    const complex operator-(const complex& c)
    {
        return complex(-c.re(),-c.im());
    } // negative of complex number
    const complex operator-(const complex& c,const complex& d)
    {
        return complex(c.re()-d.re(),c.im()-d.im());
    } // difference between complex numbers
    const complex operator+(const complex& c,const complex& d)
    {
        return complex(c.re()+d.re(),c.im()+d.im());
    } // addition of complex numbers
    const complex operator*(const complex& c,const complex& d)
    {
        return complex(c)*=d;
    } // multiplication of complex numbers
    const complex operator/(const complex& c,const complex& d)
    {
        return complex(c)/=d;
    } // division of complex numbers
};

int main(){
    complex c(1.,0.),d(3.,4.);
    print(c-d);
    print(c/d);
    return 0;
}
```

the output I am getting is:

```
complex_nums.cpp:76:59: error: ‘const complex complex::operator-(const complex&, const complex&)’ must take either zero or one argument
  const complex operator-(const complex& c,const complex& d)
                                                           ^
complex_nums.cpp:80:59: error: ‘const complex complex::operator+(const complex&, const complex&)’ must take either zero or one argument
  const complex operator+(const complex& c,const complex& d)
                                                           ^
complex_nums.cpp:84:59: error: ‘const complex complex::operator*(const complex&, const complex&)’ must take either zero or one argument
  const complex operator*(const complex& c,const complex& d)
                                                           ^
complex_nums.cpp:88:59: error: ‘const complex complex::operator/(const complex&, const complex&)’ must take exactly one argument
  const complex operator/(const complex& c,const complex& d)
                                                           ^
complex_nums.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
complex_nums.cpp:96:11: error: ‘print’ was not declared in this scope
  print(c-d);
           ^
complex_nums.cpp:97:9: error: no match for ‘operator/’ (operand types are ‘complex’ and ‘complex’)
  print(c/d);
```

Comment: The compiler is exactly telling you that to do.

Comment: What do you mean by `print()`? This code does not compile with a C++ compiler. Please provide a [MCVE]

Comment: But those member functions need two arguments.

Comment: I have defined a print() function as member function to display the complex number.

Comment: They don't need 2 arguments. You are already inside one object (the "this" class) and you get the other one as argument.

Comment: Side note -- *const complex operator-(const complex& c,const complex& d)*  -- Why is this and similar two argument functions non-static member functions?  You don't use `this` in any way inside of these functions, thus they shouldn't be non-static class members.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your operators (`+,-,*,/`) need exactly one or no arguments, unless they are friend functions. Mark all the `operator` functions as `friend`, and the code should work. Otherwise, eliminate 1 parameter from each of the operators, and instead of that use the current instance (`this`). Example for `+` operator with parameter removed:

```
const complex operator+(const complex& c)
{
    return complex(c.re()+re(),c.im()+im());
}
```

Reference of `friend` arithmetic operators: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/92-overloading-the-arithmetic-operators-using-friend-functions/

### Next Error

What are you doing with your `print()` function? It should be in global scope, because it takes a `complex` as parameter. Move `print()` out of the class into global scope, like this. If you still want to keep a `print()` for the object itself, do so, but the one for your class should look like below:

```
class complex
{
    void print(const complex&c)
    {
        printf("(%f,%f)\n",re(),im() );
    } // printing complex number
};
void print(const complex&c)
{
    printf("(%f,%f)\n",c.re(),c.im() );
} // printing complex number
```

Comment: Answer is updated @FirstStep

Answer (score 1):

Binary operators are either free functions with 2 arguments (preferred) or member functions with one argument (not so good).

You have defined member functions with 2 arguments.

Turning them into free functions by adding `friend` is one way.

Another is to make them free functions, defined outside the class but written in terms of member functions (as you have done anyway):

```
struct complex
{
 /* ... */ 
};
// class definition ends

//free function
inline complex operator/(const complex& c,const complex& d)
{
    return complex(c)/=d;
} // division of complex numbers
```

Note, this function can be improved:

```
inline complex operator/(complex c,const complex& d)
{
    c /= d;
    return c;
}
```

Also, unary operators should return `complex&`, not `const complex&`. The thing you're returning is mutable, because you just mutated it.

Comment: Hijacking your answer to post an example of using `friend` to accomplish the same thing: [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0ea426c2b7524c4a)

Comment: Also he needs `HisObject.print()` in `main()` and not just `print()`

Answer (score 0):

For the errors with the operators `must take either zero or one argument`, this is because you are implementing the non-member function as a member funciton. These should be free functions to work properly, or should only take one argument and use `this` as the other.

See this question for clarification:

[Operator overloading : member function vs. non-member function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622330/operator-overloading-member-function-vs-non-member-function)

For the error with print, I guess you are trying to call the print member function. To do that you need to do e.g. the following:

```
complex(c-d).print();
```

Comment: I corrected the problem. Thank you all :)