# How to declare operator/ overload function to operate on a const variable and a non-const variable?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, constants

I have the following code

```
#pragma once

#include "material.h"
#include "../Math/vector.h"
#include <cmath>

class LambertianMaterial : public Material
{
public:
    LambertianMaterial(Vector rho);
    Vector brdf(Vector wi) const
    {
        return mRho / M_PI; // Error here
    }

private:
    Vector mRho;
};
```

In the line corresponding to the return statement of brdf I am getting the following error

```
Invalid operands to binary expression ('const Vector' and 'double')
```

In the class vector I have declared the `operator/` like

```
Vector operator/(const float a);
```

I was thinking of redefining the method to

```
friend Vector operator/(const Vector& v, const float& a);
```

Is this a good way of doing it or is there a way so that the current definition of the operator accounts for the `const Vector` case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make it a const member function, which could be applied for const and non-const object, if it won't (and it shouldn't) modify any non-static member variables.

```
Vector operator/(const float a) const;
```

As you thought, making it non-member function (and declared as friend if necessary) could do the work too. IMO I prefer to it for `operator/`. See [Operator overloading : member function vs. non-member function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4622330/3309790) for more informations.