# How to know the number of chain custom-defined operator << calls?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have my own class where I define and use << operator like so:

```
vw& vw::operator<<(const int &a) {

    // add a to an internal buffer
    // do some work when it's the last number

    return *this;
}

...

vw inst;

inst << a << b << c << d;

...

inst << a << b;

...
```

The number of chain << calls is different every time. These numbers together represent a code and I need to do something when the code is complete.

Do I have any other options to know when it's complete rather than adding a special terminating value to each chain, like below?

```
inst << a << b << c << d << term;

...

inst << a << b << term;
```

**EDIT2** : current solution following *LogicStuff* answers:

```
--- chain.h ---
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
class chain
{
public:
    chain();
    ~chain();
};
--- chain_cutter.h ---
#pragma once
#include "chain.h"
class chain_cutter
{
    chain &inst;
public:
    explicit chain_cutter(chain &inst) : inst(inst) {
        std::cout << "cutter_constructor" << std::endl;
    }
    ~chain_cutter();
};
--- chain_cutter.cpp ---
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "chain_cutter.h"
chain_cutter::~chain_cutter()
{
    std::cout << "cutter_destructor" << std::endl;
}
--- chain.cpp ---
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "chain.h"
chain::chain()
{
    std::cout << std::endl << "chain_constructor" << std::endl;
}
chain::~chain()
{
    std::cout << std::endl << "chain_destructor" << std::endl;
}
--- flowchart.cpp ---

#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>

#include "chain.h"
#include "chain_cutter.h"

chain_cutter operator<<(chain &inst, const int &a) {
    chain_cutter cutter(inst);
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    return cutter;
}

chain_cutter&& operator<<(chain_cutter &&cutter, const int &a) {
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    return std::move(cutter);
}

int main()
{

    std::cout << "main start" << std::endl;

    chain ch;

    ch << 1 << 2 << 3;

    std::cout << std::endl << "-----" << std::endl;

    ch << 4 << 5;

    return 0;
}
```

This is the output:

```
main start

chain_constructor
cutter_constructor
1
2
3
cutter_destructor

-----
cutter_constructor
4
5
cutter_destructor
```

Comment: You'll need a terminator if you go the streaming route.  You could make a variadic  function and handle doing that in the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible without changing the current syntax.

You will have to make `inst << a` (i.e. the current `operator<<`) return a temporary instance of a "special" class, holding a reference to `inst`, implementing `operator<<` by calling `inst.operator<<`, returning reference 
 to `*this`, and then doing the extra work in its destructor, which will be called at the end of the statement.

And yes, you can keep track of the call count with it.

---

I propose these [nonmember](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622330/operator-overloading-member-function-vs-non-member-function) `operator<<` overloads (`vw_chain` is the new proxy class):

```
// Left-most operator<< call matches this
vw_chain operator<<(vw &inst, const int &a) {
    return vw_chain(inst, a);
}

// All subsequent calls within the << chain match this
vw_chain &&operator<<(vw_chain &&chain, const int &a) {
    chain.insert(a);
    return std::move(chain);
}
```

The class itself:

```
struct vw_chain
{
    explicit vw_chain(vw &inst, const int &a) :
        inst(inst)
    {
        insert(a);
    }

    ~vw_chain() {
        // do something
    }

    void insert(const int &a) {
        // This, the original operator<<, should be made accessible only to this
        // function (private, friend class declaration?), not to cause ambiguity.
        // Or, perhaps, put the implementation of the original operator<< here
        // and remove it altogether.
        inst << a;
        ++insertion_count;
    }

    vw &inst;
    size_t insertion_count = 0;
};
```

We have to pass the instance around by rvalue reference. We do the first insertion inside the `vw_chain`'s constructor, in order to get the [mandatory copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) (C++17), which works only with prvalues. Whether there will be a copy done at the `return` statement, is unspecified with NRVO and older standards. We should not rely on that.

Pre-C++17 solution:

```
struct vw_chain
{
    // We keep the constructor simpler
    vw_chain(vw &inst) : inst(inst) {}

    // Moved-from chains are disabled
    vw_chain(vw_chain &&other) :
        inst(other.inst),
        insertion_count(other.insertion_count) {
        other.is_enabled = false;
    }

    // And will not call the termination logic
    ~vw_chain() {
        if(is_enabled) {
            // do something
        }
    }

    void insert(const int &a) {
        inst << a;
        ++insertion_count;
    }

    vw &inst;
    size_t insertion_count = 0;
    bool is_enabled = true;
};

// The first overload changes to this
vw_chain operator<<(vw &inst, const int &a) {
    vw_chain chain(inst);
    chain.insert(a);
    return chain;
}
```

Comment: However this does sort of modify the "meaning" of `<<` which is expected to do the same thing each time regardless of whether it chains or not. That might be a concern.

Comment: Thank you, please see **EDIT** for questions.

Comment: @user1481126 Oops, passing by value defeated the whole purpose. I changed the code a bit and edited the last paragraph. I will try to come up with pre-C++17 compatible solution. What standard are you using?

Comment: It seems to work now, all I had to do is to change the overload code from chain_cutter operator<<(chain_cutter cutter, const int &a) { ... return cutter;} to chain_cutter&& operator<<(chain_cutter &&cutter, const int &a) { ... return std::move(cutter); }. I'm using VS 2015 so I think it's C++14.

Answer (score 5):

You can:

- Use a special final type to signal termination (a la `std::endl`).
- Avoid using `operator<<`, and defining a variadic template function instead. A variadic template function supports any number of arbitrary arguments, and knows that number at compile-time.
- Put the logic into `vw`'s destructor, and allow `operator<<` only on rvalues. E.g.

  ```
  vw{} << a << b << c;
  // `vw::~vw()` contains termination logic
  ```

Comment: This makes LogicStuff's approach a little clearer during usage. Although I'm not sure I've actually seen anyone do it this way as it "looks" a bit weird