# I cannot add two or more parameters the the bool operator in a class

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

When I try to add `bool operator==(complx a, complx b)` it says

```
  |Code      |Description
  |EO344     too many parameters for this operator function
```

I have tried using just one parameter, but I can't do it.

Here is the actual function:

```
    //boolean operators                          "|Code  |Description
    bool operator==(complx a, complx b) //error: " EO344 too many parameters for this operator function"
    {
        /*error code*/return a.real() == b.real() && a.imag() == b.imag();
    }
```

It says there are too many parameters, but my book says there's not. Can you help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Comment: In particular, see the first footnote in the "Comparison operators" section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading/4421719#4421719). (I know, it's buried, but it is there, and the linked question is a good reference.)

Comment: @JaMiT I can't even manage to find it. Where really is it?

Comment: The sections in that answer are "Assignment Operator", "Bitshift Operators (used for Stream I/O)", "Function call operator", **"Comparison operators"**, "Arithmetic Operators", "Array Subscripting", and "Operators for Pointer-like Types". So it's the fourth of the seven sections, roughly at the middle of the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a member function, `operator==()` must take one parameter, which is the right-hand side operand. The left-hand side operand is the `this` object.

It only takes two parameters when implemented as as a free, non-member function.

Note that when implementing binary operators as member functions you can run into ordering problems. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4622467/856199) for details.

Comment: So do you mean it should be: `bool operator==(complx b)`

Comment: @EpixyCoder101 Yeah. A popular convention here is to name the parameter `other`.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. **Thank you!**