# Commutative operator + overloading causes infinite recursion

Tags: c++, class, templates, type-conversion, operator-overloading

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class StringNum {
public:
    string s;
    StringNum() {s = "";}
public:
    StringNum(int n) {
        s = "";
        for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) s += "x";
    }

    operator int () {
        return s.length();
    }

    StringNum operator + (StringNum v) {
        cout << "operator + is called\n";
        int len = s.length() + v.s.length();
        StringNum res;
        for (int i=1;i<=len;i++) res.s += "x";
        return res;
    }

    template <class T>
    StringNum operator + (T value) {
        return (*this) + StringNum(value);
    }
};

template<class T>
StringNum operator + (T value, const StringNum& num) {
    cout << "operator + opposite is called\n";
    //return value + num; // infinite recursion, of course
    // return num + value;  // infinite recursion, despite StringNum + <class T> is defined
    return num + StringNum(value); // STILL infinite recursion
    //return StringNum(num) + value; // correct, output 6
}

int main()
{
    StringNum x(4);
    cout << (x + 2.5) << "\n"; // StringNum + <class T>, output 6
    int res = (2 + x);
    cout << res;
    return 0;
}
```

Class StringNum represents an integer number > 0, where length of the string is the number.

`StringNum + StringNum` are member functions and work correctly.

`StringNum + <class T>` is also a member function and works correctly.

However, for `<class T> + StringNum`, it requires a external function. However,  the behavior of `operator +` is confusing and doesn't make any sense:

```
template<class T>
StringNum operator + (T value, const StringNum& num) {
    cout << "operator + opposite is called\n";
    //return value + num; // infinite recursion, of course
    // return num + value;  // StringNum + <class T>, infinite recursion. Why??
    return num + StringNum(value); // STILL infinite recursion
    //return StringNum(num) + value; // StringNum + <class T> -> this time it's correct, output 6
}
```

How is it that `num + StringNum(value)` causes infinite recursion, while it should call `StringNum + StringNum` ? Also, why does `num + value` cause infinite recursion, while it should call `StringNum + <class T>` ? Finally, how does `StringNum(num) + value` solve the problem when `num` is a StringNum in the first place?

How can I correctly implement `commutative operator +` in this case ? Thank you.

Comment: Try `StringNum operator+(const StringNum& op1, const StringNum& op2)` as a non member function. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/4622330/10077

Comment: `s = "";
        for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) s += "x";` Can be replaced by `s = std::string(n, 'x');`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use correct constness:

```
StringNum operator + (const StringNum& v) const {
    cout << "operator + is called\n";
    int len = s.length() + v.s.length();
    StringNum res;
    for (int i=1;i<=len;i++) res.s += "x";
    return res;
}

template <class T>
StringNum operator + (T value) const {
    return (*this) + StringNum(value);
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ca9a50d5ebd89387)

As In your template,

You call `operator+` with `const StringNum&` and `StringNum`

And candidates are:

- `StringNum StringNum::operator + (StringNum v)` Doesn't match, apply only to non const lhs
- `template <class T> StringNum StringNum::operator + (T value)` Doesn't match, same reason as above
- `template<class T> StringNum operator + (T value, const StringNum& num)` Matches, so leading to infinite recursion.

Comment: Do you mean the result of operator should ALWAYS be const ? Edit: my mean the final const keyword.

Comment: @HuyĐứcLê *Do you mean the result of operator should ALWAYS be const ?* -- Which `const` are you referring to?  The argument should have been passed as `const` reference, and since the `+` function doesn't mutate any members of `StringNum`, should be marked as a `const` function.

Comment: I mean the "doesn't mutate any members" const. But could you explain how does that solve the infinite recursion (calling the wrong operator) problem ?

Comment: @HuyĐứcLê your global operator+ function take const StringNum parameter. You can not call non-const member function with const class variable. So member operator+ function was not eligable

Comment: Ohhh. I remember that now. Thank you.