# Overloading unary operator specially post-increment and pre-increment using friend keyword

Tags: c++, post-increment, pre-increment, friend-function

I know this topic might not be useful. This question can across in my mind when I was implementing friend function. In operator overloading of post-increment member function we need to write int as argument (for the sake of differentiating it from pre-increment though we don't have to pass anything) so *How de we implement* **friend return_type operator_post-increment()**?

Comment: Same as any other member/friend overloaded operator. The member function has an implicit `this` first parameter. In the friend function you need to explicitly pass the type that `this` would have been. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622330/operator-overloading-member-function-vs-non-member-function

Comment: Better link here. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we are to implement both the functionalities of pre-increment and post-increment in the same program, we will have to write 'int' as a second argument in order to differentiate it from pre-increment operator overloading.
Here below is the code for the same:

```
***#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Complex{
    int real;
    float imag;
    
    public:
        void setData(int R,float I)
        {
            real=R;
            imag=I;
        }
        void showData()
        {
            if(imag<0)
            cout<<real<<imag<<"j"<<endl;
            else
            cout<<real<<"+"<<imag<<"j"<<endl;
        }
        friend Complex operator-(Complex C);
        friend Complex operator++(Complex C);  //pre inc
        friend Complex operator++(Complex C,int); //post increment
        
};
        Complex operator-(Complex C)
        {
            Complex temp;
            temp.real=-C.real;
            temp.imag=-C.imag;
            return temp;
        }
        Complex operator++(Complex C) //pre inc
        {
            Complex temp;
            temp.real=++C.real;
            temp.imag=++C.imag;
            return temp;
        }
        Complex operator++(Complex C,int) //post inc
        {
            Complex temp;
            temp.real=C.real++;
            temp.imag=C.imag++;
            return temp;
        }
int main()
{`enter code here`
    Complex c1,c2,c3;
    c1.setData(2,-8.1);
    c1.showData();
    c2=c1++; //c2=operator++(c1); friend op post inc
    c2.showData();
    c3=++c1; //c3=operator++(c1); friend op pre inc
    c3.showData();
}***
```