# Why can't I access private members of class Box in operator<<?

Tags: c++, class, private, operator-keyword, iostream

Why can't I access private functions of class `Box` in `ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Box& B){cout << B.l << " " << B.b << " " << B.h << endl; }`?

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class Box{
    int l, b, h;
    public:
      Box(){
          l=0;
          b=0;
          h=0;
      }
      Box(int length, int breadth, int height){
          l=length;
          b=breadth;
          h=height;
      }
      bool operator < (Box &B){
          if(l < B.l)return 1;
          else if(b < B.b && l==B.l)return 1;   
          else if(h< B.h && b== B.b && l==B.l)return 1;
          else return 0;
      }

    };
    ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, const Box& B){
        cout << B.l << " " << B.b << " " << B.h ;
        return out;
    }
```

Comment: Since the purpose of `private` is to restrict access, you should add an explanation of why you think access should be allowed in this case.

Comment: The `operator<<()` function is not a member of class `Box`.   To access `private` members  of a `Box`, there needs to be a `friend` declaration (e.g. `friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &, const Box &);` within the definition of `Box`).    Also, it is inadvisable to rely on `using namespace std` in cases like this, since it can introduce ambiguity in some situations - instead use the fully qualified name `std::ostream` rather than `ostream`.

Comment: Ask yourself whether it really makes sense that `operator<<` specifically, but not other functions, should be able to access the members. My feeling is that `Box` should probably have getter functions to retrieve the values for all three. Or should it really be impossible to figure out what e.g. the length of a `Box` is? `operator<<` can then simply use the public interface.

Comment: actually, I used the getter functions in the original program and the public interface. my question should be does ostream& makes any difference.  the issue was resolved by making them freind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **problem** is that you don't have any **friend declaration** for the overloaded `operator<<` and since `l`, `b` and `h` are `private` they can't be accessed from inside the overloaded `operator<<`.

To **solve** this you can just provide a friend declaration for `operator<<` as shown below:

```
class Box{
    int l, b, h;
    //other code here as before
    
//--vvvvvv----------------------------------------->friend declaration added here
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, const Box& B);

};
//definition same as before
ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, const Box& B){
    cout << B.l << " " << B.b << " " << B.h ;
    return out;
}
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/mObPbvLlb)

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the operator overloading in two ways:

1. **Member function**

   If it is a member function, then any instance of Box, can access the private members of Box class.

   For e.g., for operator "**bool operator < (Box& b)**", when you call b1 < b2 (where b1 and b2 are instances of Box), then you can directly access private members of both b1 and b2 in the "operator <" implementation.
2. **Non-member function**

   Non-member functions, by default, cannot access the privates of a class.

   So, either the non-member overloaded operator has to be declared as a friend of Box class or you need to define public functions for the private members which will be accessed in this non-member overloaded operator.

You can also check the discussion here, which clearly explains when an overloaded operator can be implemented either as a member or a non-member function: [Operator overloading : member function vs. non-member function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622330/operator-overloading-member-function-vs-non-member-function)